# Adding CData to XML code using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, cdata

I am trying to create an XML document using Powershell. I am using System.XML.XMLTextWriter to create my document. I have searched all over looking for an answer and can't find it.

Here's what I have right now:

```
$variable = "my text"
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Legal')
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("heading")
$XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("![CDATA[]]",$Variable)
```

I would like the end result to look like:

```
 <Legal>
        <heading>
            <![CDATA[ $Variable ]]>
        </heading>
    </Legal>
```

Comment: $XmlWriter.WriteCData($Variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
$XmlWriter.WriteCData($Variable)
```

Comment: Please avoid simply dumping code, provide an explanation of what you've written too